# Using Estimator for building an LSTM network

Tags: tensorflow, lstm

I am trying to build an LSTM network using an Estimator. My data looks like

```
X = [[1,2,3], [2,3,4], ... , [98,99,100]]
y = [2, 3, ... , 99]
```

I am using an Estimator:

```
regressor = learn.Estimator(model_fn=lstm_model,
                            params=model_params,
                            )
```

where the lstm_model function is

```
def lstm_model(features, targets, mode, params):

    def lstm_cells(layers):
        if isinstance(layers[0], dict):
            return [tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(layer['steps'],state_is_tuple=True) for layer in layers]
        return [tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(steps, state_is_tuple=True) for steps in layers]

    stacked_lstm = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell(lstm_cells(params['rnn_layers']), state_is_tuple=True)
    output, layers = tf.nn.rnn(stacked_lstm, [features], dtype=tf.float32)
    return learn.models.linear_regression(output, targets)
```

and params are

```
model_params = {
    'steps': 1000,
    'learning_rate': 0.03,
    'batch_size': 24,
    'time_steps': 3,
    'rnn_layers': [{'steps': 3}],
    'dense_layers': [10, 10]
}
```

and then I do the fitting

```
regressor.fit(X, y)
```

The issue I am facing is

```
output, layers = tf.nn.rnn(stacked_lstm, [features], dtype=tf.float32)
```

requires a sequence but I am not sure how to split my features to into list of tensors. The shape of features inside the lstm_model function is (?, 3)

I have two questions, how do I do the training in batches? and how do I split 'features' so

```
output, layers = tf.nn.rnn(stacked_lstm, [features], dtype=tf.float32)
```

doesn't throw and error. The error I am getting is

```
    raise TypeError("%s that don't all match." % prefix)
TypeError: Tensors in list passed to 'values' of 'Concat' Op have types [float64, float32] that don't all match.
```

I am using tensorflow 0.12

Answer (score 1):

I had to set the shape for features to be 
(batch_size, time_step, 1) or (None, time_step, 1) and then unstack the features to go in the rnn. Unstacking the features in the "time_step" so you have a list of tensors with the size of time steps and the shape for each tensor should be (None, 1) or (batch_size, 1)